# Solving integrals that are related to the standard normal distribution

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, solution-verification, expected-value

Let X be a continuous RV with probability density function $f(x) = xe^{-x^2/2},$ $x>0$.

Part A): Compute $E[X]$

Part B): Compute $Var(X)$

Part C): Let $Z = X^2$. Determine the distribution of $Z$ (meaning the cumulative distribution function of $Z$). My approach:

Part A):

$E[X]$  = $\int_0^{\infty}x^2e^{-x^2/2}dx = \sqrt{2\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}x^2e^{-x^2/2}dx = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}E[Z^2]}2$ where Z is the standard normal distribution. I am not sure I did the last step right. If it is correct, then I used that $E[Z^2] = Var(Z) + E[Z]^2 = 1 + 0^2 = 1$ to get that $E[X] = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}2$. Is it correct?

Part B):
I am a little lazy to write out the steps but I just used a change of variable to get that $E[X^2] = \int_0^{\infty}x^3e^{-x^2/2}dx = 1$.

Part C): I really am not sure what to do here. What I tried was:
$F_Z(a) = P(Z < a) = P(X^2 < a) = P(-\sqrt{a} < X < \sqrt{a}) = \int_{-\sqrt{a}}^{\sqrt{a}}x^2e^{-x^2/2}dx$, but here the integral is the same as in Part A, except with different bounds of integration, so I can not use the same trick that I tried in Part A).

I understand if people don't want to help with the second part since I didn't take the time to show my work. Mostly looking for validation that the first part is correct and some hints or feedback for Part C. Thanks

Comment: The first part is correct. For part c, note that $X > 0$. So $F_Z(z) = \Pr(Z < z) = \Pr(X^2 < z) = \Pr(X < \sqrt{z}) = F_X(\sqrt{z}) = \int_{0}^{\sqrt{z}} x e^{-x^2/2} \ \mathrm{d}x$. Substitute $x^2 = t$ and obtain the integral.

Comment: You might note that your $X$ has a Rayleigh or $\chi_2$ distribution so $Z=X^2$ has a  $\chi^2_2$ distribution and a relatively simple CDF

Comment: @Henry We were not taught about Rayleigh distributions as part of the curriculum. So I guess we have to solve things with assuming no prior knowledge of that distribution